# OpenOPC opc.read() hangs up for 15 minutes

Tags: python, opc

I am using openOPC 1.3.1. I noticed that from time to time opc.read() hangs. Here is how I use it:

```
opc.read(opc.list('Ethernet_DWG.*', recursive=True), include_error=True, timeout=10)
```

The strange thing is that when it hangs, it does it for *exactly* 15 minutes everytime. The timeout parameter does not influence that, unfortunately.

Any clues how to solve that?

Comment: Are you making a remote connection?

Comment: @Ronaldo No. I connect to a local opc server.